# what to use instead of JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf for generating excel report?

Tags: jasper-reports, report

```
byte[] bytes=JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(),resource,new  JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datalist)).
```

i want to return bytes generating excel report

Answer (score 1):

You should use **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter** exporter class.

The sample for result output as **`java.io.OutputStream`**:

```java
JasperPrint JasperPrint = (JasperPrint)JRLoader.loadObject(sourceFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, JasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, os);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Or you can set ***`RExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME`*** parameter for getting file as result.